# Extracting Promise Chain to an external function

Tags: javascript, promise

So Promises make everything so much cleaner and all but how do I extrapolate the end of a promise chain to an external function?

For example:

```
SomePromise.then(result => {
    // do stuff here
}).catch(err => {
    // do more stuff here
})

SomePromise2.then(result => {
    // do stuff here
}).catch(err => {
    // do more stuff here
})

SomePromise3.then(result => {
    // do stuff here
}).catch(err => {
    // do more stuff here
})
```

Somehow, I'd like to extract the then and catch so that I can pass a function into the then like such:

```
SomePromise.then(handler);
SomePromise2.then(handler);
SomePromise3.then(handler);
```

I suppose I could extract the entire Promise into a function and pass parameters to and from there but that feels a bit clunky. Any elegant solutions?

Edit: I should elaborate that I'm focusing on the catch part. Imagine multiple different queries with identical data-parsers and error handlers.

Edit 2: In hindsight I realize now that I could just extrapolate

```
handler = () => {}
errorHandler = () => {}

Promise.then(handler)
       .catch(errorHandler)
```

but the

Comment: `async`/`await` keywords? https://javascripr.info/async-await

Comment: It’s not really clear what you’re asking for. How would this be used?

Comment: @kellys yeah async/await is okay

Comment: @-Ry- so imagine you have a different queries with identical error handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let p1=Promise.resolve(1);
function handler(data){console.log(data)};
function errorHandler(error){console.log(error)};
p1.then(handler,errorHandler);
```

Multiple things here, your code you are expecting is:

SomePromise.then(handler);

However it should be in actual as

function handler(data){};
SomePromise.then((data)=>handler(data));

Comment: How would I catch errors in the handler with this method?

Comment: Passing the handler function as a one parameter function should bypass the need for (data)=>handler(data); I was just using shorthand

Comment: @DucksEatTurtles I have edited my code snippet for both error and success.

Comment: Huh, I wasn't aware you could pass a second parameter into then like that to act as your catch